# KVM/Qemu allocated memory not showing in guest

Tags: memory, qemu, kvm

So we have a RHEL 7.6 workstation with 128 gigs of ram. The OS sees all the ram and 80 cors (40 HT)

We have 1 guest with 8 CPUs and 32gigs of ram running RHEL 7.6 workstation as well.

We are trying to create another guest with 64 CPUs and 80 gigs of ram.

We setup the system using virt-manager and PXE boot the system to install the OS.

All this goes without a hitch, but when we log in after the system is build with PXE and do a free -g it only shows 2 gigs instead of 80 gigs.

Any ideas?

Thanks!
Joe

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue was related to using uefi bios and the OVMF.x86_64 package. Once we went back to a normal bios and no nvram, the issue went away.

Hope this helps someone :).
Joe